# NO Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i have a host in godaddy with Linux os i made a website with codeigniter framework and i make page.
in this i made a side menu with ajax call.
when i click on this menu it doesn't work and i got

```html
XMLHttpRequest cannot load - Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

i searched for this error and i got an idea that i must edit in .htaccess file
i wrote this code

```html
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

but it doesn't work.
i don't know how i can fix it

Comment: does the `ajax call` call your site or some other site?

Comment: you have to handle cors request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please remove WWW prefix from your ajax call i have see your site load without WWW and your ajax call have www prefix

OR

you can use the jsonp datatype for ajax call
here is the detail : https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.abuqir.net/c_about/about_policy. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://abuqir.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: Please check your ajax request have www prefix. please remove www prefix

Comment: i removed it but still nothing happend

Comment: I can still see the www in your json request

Comment: where it? i have removed it i'm sure please show me where

Comment: There is caching in my side please try get instead of post I have see 403 (Forbidden) error now

Comment: Remote Address:107.180.2.50:80
Request URL:http://abuqir.net/c_about/about_brief
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://abuqir.net
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 05 Oct 2015 07:12:19 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5
Server:Apache/2.4.12
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.43

Comment: Yes please change POST to GET

Comment: Please change $.POST to $.GET

Comment: thanx sooooooooooooooooooooo much u r the one

Comment: and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score -1):

You are making cross domain request, so you need to enable `cors` at server end, or if you don't want to enable it at server end, you need to add `cors` extension to chrome. But i will recommend you to enable `cors` at server end.

Comment: how can i  enable cors at server end ?